# Let R and S are "Congruence modulo 4" and "Congruence modul0 6" relations respectively on set of integers, R={(a,b)| a=b(mod 4), S={(a,b)| a=b(mod 6)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let R and S are "Congruence modulo 4" and "Congruence modul0 6" relations respectively on set of integers, R={(a,b)| a=b(mod 4), S={(a,b)| a=b(mod 6). Calculate:-
1. R union S
2. R intersection S
3. R-S
4. S-R
5. R XOR S
"=" above means congruence modulo.
I didn't understand this question at all. I'm new to relations. Also, explain why do we have to take LCM of 4 and 6. Saw the solution

Comment: This site want to teach people. This is not for "problem solving". Problem solving is a side effect of learning. Then it is important, to be answered, show some effort by your side, what you tried to solve the problem, what you dont understand, etc...

Answer (score 0):

For example:

$$R\cup S=\left\{\;(a,b)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\;/\;a=b\pmod 4\;\;\color{red}{\text{or}}\;\;a=b\pmod 6\;\right\}$$

So for example, we have that

$$(3,7)\,,\,(-5,1),\,(14,18)\in R\cup S\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;(1,3),\,(-3,2)\notin R\cup S$$

Or also

$$R\cap S=\left\{\;(a,b)\in\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\;/\;a=b\pmod 4\;\;\color{red}{\text{and also}}\;\;a=b\pmod 6\;\right\}$$

For example,

$$(0,12),\,(-35,-23), (-11,1),\,(5,17)\in R\cap S\;,\;\;\text{but}\;\;(0,4),\,(0,6),\,(-4,5),\,(2,15)\notin R\cap S$$

You now must try the rest by yourself. There are thousands of sites in the web which deal with this basic and very important stuff. Just google "relations on sets" or something like that, and of course scores of books, too.